# How can I hook up custom email provider in ELMAH?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I've asked this on the elmah group in google groups but am still mystified so I thought I'd throw it out to a larger pool.  Here's the original note with my code as it currently stands.

---

I have ELMAH set up on my MVC 5 application and I want to use a custom email service to send email instead of using the smtp send that is set up by default.  (This is an organizational preference.) I've been poking around at it but can't figure out how to do this.  My service call is working just fine, but I can't hook it up so that it runs when there is an exception.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

What I've got set up is the following:

Web.config (removed non-elmah-related lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections><appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
</appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BFRDPDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="blahblah;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error" />
    </customErrors>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="BFRDP.Infrastructure.ErrorMailModule" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="BFRDP.Infrastructure.ErrorMailModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah"
              connectionStringName="BFRDPDB"
              applicationName="FarmAnswers.org" /> 
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
             path="elmah.axd"
             type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SuperAdmin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH"
             verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
             path="elmah"
             type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"
             preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And my ErrorMailModule.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace BFRDP.Infrastructure
{/// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ErrorMailModule
    /// </summary>
    public class ErrorMailModule : Elmah.ErrorMailModule
    {
        public ErrorMailModule()
        {
        }



        protected override void SendMail(MailMessage mail)
        {
            if (mail == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("mail");
            // Code to send email here through internal provider
        }

    }
}
```

My error is indeed logged in the database, but the code to send the email is never reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to add a new errorLog in the <elmah> section in web.config that points to your email logger?

Comment: Not sure but it seems unlikely. What would such a thing look like?

Comment: Close, Mike.  I needed to add an errorMail setting in the <elmah> section. The settings are meaningless; it just has to be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added the errorMail settings in the  section of my web.config and the app was able to get to my custom module:

```html
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="BFRDPDB" applicationName="FarmAnswers.org" />
    <errorMail
    from="elmah@example.com"
    to="admin@example.com"
    subject="..."
    priority="Low"
    async="true"
    smtpPort="25"
    smtpServer="smtp.example.com"
    useSsl="true"
    userName="johndoe"
    password="secret"
    noYsod="true" />
  </elmah>
```